# Изменения цвета

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function randomColor() {
  function colorNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }
  setInterval(function() {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
    for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.background = 'rgb(' + colorNum() + ',' + colorNum() + ',' + colorNum() + ')';
    }
  }, 500)
}
```

```html
<div class='element'>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class='element'>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="randomColor()" id='random'>Click For Random Colors</button>
```

Comment: маловато кода, нет разметки

Comment: В чем суть вопроса?

Answer (score 5):

Про часовую стрелку - не понял.

```js
function randomColor() {
  function colorNum() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }
  let i = 0;
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
  setInterval(function() {
    elements[i].style.background = 'rgb(' + colorNum() + ',' + colorNum() + ',' + colorNum() + ')';
    i = (i + 1) % elements.length;
  }, 100)
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='element'>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class='element'>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="randomColor()" id='random'>Click For Random Colors</button>
```

Comment: может не надо setInterval?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Могу, конечно, его закомментировать, но боюсь, тогда работать не будет.

Comment: я про requestAnimationFrame.., правда с ним несколько сложнее

Comment: если вы можете подсказать, какой инструмент нужно использовать для достижения цели -  подскажите :)

Comment: @kek если результат, который получается в этом посте вас устраивает - то такое решение и используйте